# scheduled at jobs deployed via a python script do not append to same log file

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to deploy multiple 'at' jobs via a python script in linux.
Jobs are deployed perfectly using below code snippet.

```
def Deploy_at():
''' This function will deploy nine "at" jobs 
    running at an interval of one minute to capture 
    swap usage '''

    repeat = 1
    while repeat <= 9:
        c1 = 'at,now + %d min' % repeat
        sched_cmd = list(c1.split(','))
        command = "echo repeat >> data_minor.log"

        p = Popen(sched_cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
        p.communicate(command)
        repeat += 1
```

However the actual command run via at jobs :

command = "echo repeat >> data_minor.log"

does not log output to data_minor.log . Instead 9 files are created with filenames as data_minor.logmarcinDELIMITER2a97d38f.

Need to understand why output is logged to multiple files and how to log output to single file.

Comment: Anybody Please .....

Comment: unrelated: (1) use `for in range(1, 10):`, to make the loop. (2) `.split()` already returns a list (drop `list()` around it). (3) you could use `threading.Timer` to postpone a command instead of `at`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got my code to work.
This is how I did it.

```
def Deploy_at():
    ''' This function will deploy nine "at" jobs 
    running at an interval of one minute to capture 
        swap usage '''

    repeat = 1
    while repeat <= 9:
        c1 = 'at,now + %d min' % repeat
        sched_cmd = list(c1.split(','))
        command = '/usr/bin/python /home/ricky/python-test/cal_swap.py -m trigger\n'

        p = Popen(sched_cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
        p.communicate(command)
        repeat += 1
```

Comment: I don't see ` data_minor.log` being mention in the code anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @J.F. Sebastian for you answer . My question had only one of the functions used in my script. The trigger function handles writing the output to data_minor.log .I will post the whole script for you soon !!!.
The logic that works behind the script is that when ever the threshold value ,as defined in the script ,is met , the script deploys 9 at jobs to capture data and exit. I don't want my script to keep on waiting for 9 minutes. The script is run via a cron job every 10 minutes , so the script decides what to do next based on the code written.